# Need help to compare two sets of nodes in xsl

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, foreach

Here's piece of my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ran.xsl"?>
    <Authentication isLogged="1" uid="40">
        <GetUserMenu>
            <MenuList>
                <row MenuID="1" MenuTitle="menu1"/>
                <row MenuID="2" MenuTitle="menu2"/>
                <row MenuID="3" MenuTitle="menu3"/>
                <row MenuID="4" MenuTitle="menu4"/>
            </MenuList>

            <FunctionList>
                <row FunctionID="1" FunctionTitle="submenu1" MenuID="1" WorkflowName="ImportDataWithoutFile" Order="1"/>
                <row FunctionID="2" FunctionTitle="submenu2" MenuID="1" WorkflowName="ImportDataFromFile" Order="2"/>
                <row FunctionID="2" FunctionTitle="submenu2" MenuID="3" WorkflowName="ImportDataFromFile" Order="2"/>
            </FunctionList>
        </GetUserMenu>
    </Authentication>
```

Html output should be something like this:

```
<div id="menu">
    <div>menu1
         <div class="subMenu">
             <div>submenu1
             </div>
             <div>submenu2
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div>menu2
         <div class="subMenu">
         </div>
    </div>
    <div>menu3
         <div class="subMenu">
             <div>submenu3
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div>menu4
         <div class="subMenu">
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and piece of xsl:

```
<xsl:template match="//Authentication/GetUserMenu">
        <div>
            <xsl:for-each select="//MenuList/row">
                <div><xsl:value-of select="@MenuID"/></div>
                tu
                <xsl:for-each select="//FunctionList/row[">
                    <div><xsl:value-of select="@MenuID"/></div>
                </xsl:for-each>
                tu
            </xsl:for-each>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
```

I would like to make my xsl do this:

1. In outer for-each cycle xsl reads value of MenuId attribute of `<row>` of `<MenuList>`.
2. then in inner cycle for-each my xsl compares that value to every value of MenuAttribute of `<row>`'s of `<FunctionList>`
3. then my xsl reads the value of MenuId attribute of following `<row>` of `<MenuList>` and repeats second step
   By doing this i will be able to make html menu buttons and submenu buttons below corresponding button. connection between menu and submenu buttons is recognized by MenuId attribute

In normal programming language what i am trying to do (with xsl) would look like this:

```
foreach (xitems as xitem)
    foreach (yitems as yitem)
       if xitem == yitem do smth
```

Could anyone give any advice or modify my code in order to solve my issue? I would be grateful

Comment: If you want help with the XSLT way of transforming your XML input into some HTML output then consider to show a small but representative sample of the XML input and the corresponding HTML output you want to create. Then we can help with the right XSLT code. "Translating" code in a "normal" programming language to XSLT code is not a good approach to solving problems with XSLT.

Comment: i have posted expected html output. if you are lacking any more details, tell me. I would be grateful for some help

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use an `xsl:key` and the `key` function as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="k1" match="FunctionList/row" use="@MenuID"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Authentication/GetUserMenu"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Authentication/GetUserMenu">
    <div>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="MenuList/row"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="MenuList/row">
    <div>
      <xsl:value-of select="@MenuTitle"/>
      <div class="subMenu">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('k1', @MenuID)"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="FunctionList/row">
    <div>
      <xsl:value-of select="@FunctionTitle"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With that code and the input you posted Saxon 6.5.5 outputs

```
<div>
   <div>menu1
      <div class="subMenu">
         <div>submenu1</div>
         <div>submenu2</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div>menu2
      <div class="subMenu"></div>
   </div>
   <div>menu3
      <div class="subMenu">
         <div>submenu2</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div>menu4
      <div class="subMenu"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

That's not quite what you posted as the desired result but I am not sure where the `submenu3` comes from as there is no such item in the XML input.

Answer (score 0):

Good question, +1.

**This shorter and simpler (not using keys) transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <div id="menu">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </div>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="MenuList/row">
  <div>
   <xsl:value-of select="@MenuTitle"/>
   <div class="subMenu">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="extract" select=
    "../../FunctionList
              /row[@MenuID = current()/@MenuID]
    "/>
   </div>
  </div>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="FunctionList/row" mode="extract">
   <div><xsl:value-of select="@FunctionTitle"/></div>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Authentication isLogged="1" uid="40">
    <GetUserMenu>
        <MenuList>
            <row MenuID="1" MenuTitle="menu1"/>
            <row MenuID="2" MenuTitle="menu2"/>
            <row MenuID="3" MenuTitle="menu3"/>
            <row MenuID="4" MenuTitle="menu4"/>
        </MenuList>
        <FunctionList>
            <row FunctionID="1" FunctionTitle="submenu1" MenuID="1"
                 WorkflowName="ImportDataWithoutFile" Order="1"/>
            <row FunctionID="2" FunctionTitle="submenu2" MenuID="1"
                 WorkflowName="ImportDataFromFile" Order="2"/>
            <row FunctionID="2" FunctionTitle="submenu3" MenuID="3"
                 WorkflowName="ImportDataFromFile" Order="2"/>
        </FunctionList>
    </GetUserMenu>
</Authentication>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<div id="menu">
   <div>menu1<div class="subMenu">
         <div>submenu1</div>
         <div>submenu2</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div>menu2<div class="subMenu"/>
   </div>
   <div>menu3<div class="subMenu">
         <div>submenu3</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div>menu4<div class="subMenu"/>
   </div>
</div>
```